# Find out version of the web engine of your browser by an online service

Tags: website

Is there a website which returns the type and version of the web engine (for example WebKit or Gecko) my browser uses?

Comment: For the type, there is always Wikipedia’s [list of web browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more descriptive version is **[UserAgentString.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/)**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, see http://whatsmyuseragent.com/